# PHP. Работа со строками

Tags: php, строки

Есть строка со словами 
`$words = "аркада,мороженное,собака,камаз,главная,тренировка,робот,ёлка."`
Слова разделены запятыми, а в конце точка.
Нужно вывести слова, первые буквы в которых идут в алфавитном порядке, то есть должно быть так: *аркада,главная,ёлка,камаз,мороженное,робот,собака,тренировка*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$words = "аркада,мороженное,собака,камаз,главная,тренировка,робот,банан,ёлка.";
$words = explode(',', trim($words, '.'));
asort($words);
$words = implode(',', $words) . '.';
print_r($words);
введите сюда код
```

с **ёлкой** (`елка` отсортируется норм) будет конфуз - буква **Ё** как-то игнорируется кодировками. В таблице Кириллических символов Юникода **Ё** входит в группу **0400**. Тогда, как сам алфавит начинается с **0410** 
¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Хотя я видел в инете примеры, где сортировка с учётом Ё прокатывала, но сейчас попробывал разные подходы - нихрена.
У кого Винда (у мну убунта) - попробуйте, может отработает:

```
//setlocale(LC_ALL, "russian");
$words = "аркада,мороженное,собака,камаз,главная,тренировка,робот,банан,ёлка.";
$words = iconv('utf-8', 'windows-1251', $words);
$words = explode(',', trim($words, '.'));
sort($words, SORT_LOCALE_STRING);
$words = implode(',', $words) . '.';
$words = iconv('windows-1251', 'utf-8', $words);
print_r($words);
```